# Adding nvarchar values as Time using SUM function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

I am still a rookie in SQL Server so I can't quite figure this one out.

I have a column that is filled with `nvarchar` values that I need to sum as `durationOfWork`, so it needs to do the sum function for time values.

The columns are like this:

```
DurationOfWork  FirstName
--------------------------
1h:30min        Peter
2h:0min         Sandra
0h:10min        Peter
5h:32min        Peter
2h:0min         Dave
1h:43min        Dave
0h:25min        Sandra
```

I need to return for each Person the sum of their durations of work.

```
SUM(DurationOfWork)  FirstName
------------------------------
7h:12min             Peter
2h:25min             Sandra
3h:43min             Dave
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I *highly* recommend changing your data type here. Fix the design from a `varchar` to a `time`, or use a numerical data type and store the "periods". Considering that the lowest denominator is minutes, then `1` representing a minute would seem suitable (so the first 2 rows would have values of `90` and `120` respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a pain.  I would recommend calculating the duration as minutes or decimal hours, instead of converting back to a string.  The idea is to extract what you want from the string and put it in a better format:

```
select firstname,
       sum( convert(int, left(durationofwork, 1)) * 60 +
            convert(int, substring(durationofwork, 4, 2))
          ) as duration_minutes
from t
group by firstname;
```

If your values are always less than 24 hours -- which they seem to be based on the format -- then I would suggest storing them as `time` values rather than strings.  That said, `sum()`s might exceed 24 hours, so you can't use `time`s for aggregated results.

EDIT:

To handle the variable minutes:

```
select firstname,
       sum( convert(int, left(durationofwork, 1)) * 60 +
            convert(int, replace(substring(durationofwork, 4, 2), 'm', ''))
          ) as duration_minutes
from t
group by firstname;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but this would only work if the right side is always the same length. I corrected my Input values , if there are no minutes then it writes ":0min" not ":00min" - that was my copy mistake, sorry. Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the data type , since I am not admin

Comment: @AmilaBečirović . . . Your original data had `00` in that case.  I added a small adjustment to handle that.

Comment: thank you for the help... yes I noticed it too late, sorry for that ...again, thank you for all your help